# Anharmonic oscillator on quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, oscillators, anharmonic-oscillators

I'm studying the following Hamiltonian for an anharmonic oscillator in quantum mechanics:

\begin{equation}
\hat{H} = \frac{1}{2 m} \left( \hat{\vec{p}} - \frac{e}{c} \hat{\vec{A}} \right) + \frac{ m \omega_0^2}{2} \hat{\vec{r}} - e E \hat{z}
\end{equation}
with $\vec{A} = (-y, x, 0)$ and $\hat{H} \Psi = \epsilon \Psi$.

Now, I've gone to cylindrical coordinates and separated variables, then assuming $\Psi(\rho , \phi, z) = \Phi(\rho) \, \Phi(z) \, e^{- i M \phi}$, I got for the $z$ component:

\begin{equation}
\left[ -\frac{\hbar ^2}{2 m} \frac{d^2}{d z^2} + \frac{m \omega_0 ^2}{2} z^2 - (\epsilon_2 + e E z) \right] \Phi(z) = 0,
\end{equation}

where $\epsilon_2$ is the eigenvalue for this equation and $\epsilon_1$ is the eigenvalue for the radial equation (not important here), so that $\epsilon = \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2$.

**I have to demonstrate that:**
\begin{equation}
\epsilon_2 = h \omega_0 (n + 1/2) - \frac{(e E)^2}{2 m \omega_0 ^2}.
\end{equation}

**What I've done so far:**

I've assumed that for $ z \rightarrow \infty$, $\Phi(z) \approx e^{ -a z^2}$, and got that $a = m \omega_0/(2 \hbar)$ then, assuming
\begin{equation}
\Phi(z) = F(z) \exp\left[- \frac{m \omega_0}{2 \hbar} z^2\right],
\end{equation}
I get for $F(z)$:
\begin{equation}
-\frac{\hbar}{2 m} \frac{d^2}{dz^2} F(z) + \hbar \omega_0 z \frac{d}{d z} F(z) + \left( \frac{\hbar \omega_0}{2} - \epsilon_2 - e E z\right) F(z) = 0,
\end{equation}
 then I've tried going $\eta = \sqrt{\frac{m \omega_0}{\hbar}} z$, and with the Frobenius Method I got \to a recurrence formula for the coefficients, but It doesn't get to the result, so I think there should be a trick in the middle of the process, or another variable substitution has to be made.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Complete the square and shift z.

Comment: @AHusain on the last term (with F(z)) ?